# Ship android device with pre installed app from Google Play

Tags: google, accounts, multiple-devices

We develop an Android app that is meant to run on tablets in restaurant environments. We use standard Samsung Galaxy tablets that we ship to our customers with some custom settings:

- Pre-install our app
- Change background image

To install the app from Google Play, we have to create a Google Account for them. This process is today very manual and requires us to go through the Google Account signup process for each device. We often get rate-limited and Google keep blocking our mobile phone numbers for account activation. So this is a big issue for us.

How can we solve this? To retain a good user experience, we have to install the app on the tablet before shipping it. Changing the background image is something we could live without. We are developers and can definitely do whatever we need.

Comment: You want to solve issue of Google blocking your mobile phone numbers? Or something else?

Comment: No, I want to find the best sollution on how we can pre install the app before shipping it. Installing it manually works if we can solve the blocking of phone numbers issue. By ideally we could do something better. I'm looking for something similar to the device management you can do i gsuite for your employees.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to the Android Stack Exchange. They'll be able to walk you through loading an app outside of the Google Play.

Comment: For enterprise device there is the [Zero touch enrollment](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#zero-touch_enrollment) however it requires specially prepared devices.

Comment: you can install apk without google play. btw it's suspicious to ship devices with pre-bounded google account to customers (with regard to the [Find My Device](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) tracking and remote administration capability)